# Can I add SiriKit support to my app without a paid Apple Developer Program membership?

Tags: ios, sirikit

I'm learning iOS app development, and I want to add sirikit support to my app? Is there any way I can do it without a paid Apple Developer Program membership?

I set Siri to YES in the .entitlements file, but I can only run my app on a simulator, not a physical device. I would like to test my app on a physical device. When I try to run it on my iPhone, xcode informs me that my development team does not support the Siri capability.

Is there some way around this restriction? I'm creating iOS apps as a hobby, and I can't afford to pay $99 a year.

Answer (score 2):

You need developer account, read [here](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6) what is supported for free accounts.